# How can I set identity column in return table of PostgreSql Function?

Tags: postgresql, stored-functions, set-returning-functions

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."TestFunc"
(     
    "param1" TEXT, 
    "param2" TEXT 
) 
RETURNS TABLE  
( 
  ---------How can I set identiy like that
  "ID" integer GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1),
  "Data" TEXT
)  
AS $$
BEGIN  
    ---body...
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't and you don't need to.

`identity` is not a data type, it's an attribute that describes how values are **generated** when you insert a row that doesn't specify a value. Once the column value is generated and stored, the "identity" attribute is meaningless.

So just define your result column as `integer`

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."TestFunc"
(     
    "param1" TEXT, 
    "param2" TEXT 
) 
RETURNS TABLE  
( 
  "ID" integer,
  "Data" TEXT
)  
AS $$
BEGIN  
    ---body...
END; 
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

---

And please [stop using](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it.

Comment: I don't set  "ID" , I want to increase automatically that. How can I do ?

Comment: @İlyasDerse: you need to do that inside the code (the `---body---` part) where you generate the result of that function.

Answer (score 0):

`RETURNS TABLE` does not mean that the function will create a table. It just means that the result will look like a table, that is, have several rows. This table is not persistent, so it makes no sense to specify what should happen if you insert rows into it.